# Python Pandas Get Row Position Name instead of Index Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have the below dataframe and I am trying to calculate the absolute change for each City (row) and print the city name for the city with the largest value. I am able to get the absolute change but instead of getting the city name I am only able to get the index value.  Is there a way I can get the city name instead of the index value. In the example below I am getting index value 3 instead of "Dallas".

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'City': ['Chicago', 'Atlanta', 'New York', 'Dallas'],
                   'col1': [10, 15, 80, 200],
                   'col2': [45, 75, 90, 5],
                   'col3': [25, 35, 60, 420],
                   'col4': [60, 105, 325, 55]})
```

Output:

```
       City  col1  col2  col3  col4
0   Chicago    10    45    25    60
1   Atlanta    15    75    35   105
2  New York    80    90    60   325
3    Dallas   200     5   420    55
```

Obtain Max Absolute Value of col1-col4

```
diff_row = df.max(axis=1) - df.min(axis=1)
print(diff_row.idxmax())
```

Current Output:

```
3
```

Desired Output:

```
Dallas
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the index label to `loc` and the col of interest:

```
In[198]:
df.loc[diff_row.idxmax(), 'City']

Out[198]: 'Dallas'
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a step back and using `numpy.ptp` (peak to peak) to do the subtraction of max less min.

```
df.set_index('City').apply(np.ptp, 1).idxmax()

'Dallas'
```

---

We can push more over to `numpy` with

```
df.City.values[np.ptp(df.set_index('City').values, 1).argmax()]

'Dallas'
```

---

**Timing**

```
%timeit df.City.values[np.ptp(df.set_index('City').values, 1).argmax()]
%timeit df.set_index('City').apply(np.ptp, 1).idxmax()
1000 loops, best of 3: 399 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.03 ms per loop

%%timeit 
diff_row = df.max(axis=1) - df.min(axis=1)
df.loc[diff_row.idxmax(), 'City']
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.24 ms per loop
```

Comment: This was also a cool way to do it. Unfortunately I needed to accomplish this without numpy. But will keep this for future reference. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @MBasith if you have pandas, you have `numpy` and can always reference it with `pd.np`.  pandas imports numpy.  Also, if you found this useful, feel free to up-vote the answer.